# Difference in Rest API / Web Service / Web API

Tags: web-services, rest, webapi

I have read all over the internet up and down about the differences in these three things and to me the waters seem incredibly muddy. I'm curious if anyone has any very clear way of explaining or identifying the differences between these three categories. Examples would be helpful.

I can read the differences all day, but nothing is computing with me. A Web Service and a Web API both do the same thing, I don't get it, and a REST API is just a type of Web API so how are these 3 different things?

Comment: web service is the concept,
web api is the framework,
rest api is an architectural style

Comment: if that was the case I don't understand why my architect has these 3 entities on the architectural diagram as 3 separate components.

Comment: Perhaps your architect has some term misconception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **Web Service** is a way to expose a system functionality in a machine-readable way over HTTP. The popular formats are SOAP, JSON or other XML schemas, but anything both sides understand will do.

A **REST API** is one architecture to design a Web Service, where resources are identified by URLs, and actions on them are identified by HTTP VERBS (GET, POST, DELETE, PUT etc.)

**Web API** is the Microsoft offering to implement a Web Service, REST or other. SOAP is not supported out of the box in Web API, but can be implemented.